# real time object detection based on color in opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv, robotics

I am new to opencv. I saw many tutorials on color detection. My camera is rotating and I want it to stop rotation when it detects, say, a blue color. How can I check whether any blue object has come into my frame? I want it to be in the centre of the frame. Basically I want a feedback, maybe a flag bit, when a blue color is detected. I am using opencv2 and python. Please help

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while(1):

    # Take each frame
    _, frame = cap.read()

    # Convert BGR to HSV
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # define range of blue color in HSV
    lower_blue = np.array([110,50,50])
    upper_blue = np.array([130,255,255])

    # Threshold the HSV image to get only blue colors
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_green, upper_green)

    # Bitwise-AND mask and original image
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)
```

I did this much. Now what should I check?? if `res` is a zero matrix??  That is to get an acknowledgement if a blue object is detected.

I want something like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0PXnzAAKro8. So, how should I check whether a blue object has been detected.

Comment: please check https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html#converting-colorspaces

Comment: I tried this code. Its only a part of the program i want. With this program I understand when a blue object comes into the frame. How can the robot check whether a blue object has been detected? Maybe its an 'if condition' that I want. Please hel @C.CanberkBaci

Comment: find contours, get their area. check if your object is big enough.

Comment: I got an error using "lower_green" as indicated in the sample code, and this code. Seems that the code should say "lower_blue"